# Two go files having package declaration main inside a package

Tags: go

So i have created a package named `app` inside which there are two go files named `entry.go` and `entry1.go` where `entry.go` is having function main while `entry1.go` is having a function which is being called by `entry.go`.

content of `entry.go`:

```
package main 

import "fmt"
import "app"

func main(){
    fmt.Println("app/entry.go")
    app.FunctionOne()
}
```

content of `entry1.go`:

```
package main

func FunctionOne() {
    fmt.Println("this is having different name")
}
```

on running go build it shows import cycle

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to import `app`! you're in the same package which is `main` package.

just remove the extra import, and use `FunctionOne()` no need for `app`

Comment: Both files have `package main`, so they are not in `package app`.

Comment: After remove import "app", also need to change app.FunctionOne() to FunctionOne().